# Understanding matrix operations in Blender

Tags: python, blender

I need to refine my understanding of matrix operations in Blender, specifically verion 2.8

This following code does a number of object manipulations

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import math


bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects['Cube'])

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))

# create a location matrix
mat_loc = mathutils.Matrix.Translation((5.0, 0.0, 0.0))

# create a rotation matrix
mat_rot = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(45.0), 4, 'Z')
mat_rot2 = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(-45.0), 4, 'X')


# initiallay Suzanne and world coordinate system are identical. 
suz.matrix_world = suz.matrix_world @ mat_loc 
# this rotates around global z-axis
suz.matrix_world = mat_rot @ suz.matrix_world
# this rotates around local x-axis
suz.matrix_world = suz.matrix_world @ mat_rot2
```

In the last two operations, the suz object is rotated. Why does the axis of rotation change from local to global depending on matrix_world being first or last in the matrix multiplication?

Comment: Unless you **really** want to understand, just accept that with matrices the order matters. While you know that `3*2` gives the same result as `2*3`, when you get into [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) things aren't that simple as you are multiplying two grids of numbers. Maybe [this article](https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2016/01/21/matrices-mlk-day/) can help. Also you might be able to get a better explanation if you provide the matrices contents and  ask at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sambler. I will study a linear algebra a bit. But I'm not sure I really want to understand. I just want to be able to switch between local and global rotation. Which I seemingly can.

Comment: I found these two youtube videos very helpful. I can answer my question myself: https://youtu.be/4I2S5Xhf24o https://youtu.be/KAW7lXxMSb4